# Comment reformuler "laisser tomber" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Il y a quelques années en voyage aux États-Unis j'ai été confronté à un problème de traduction concernant l'expression "laisser tomber", expression utilisée au cours d'une conversation quand on souhaite abandonner une explication.

C'est une expression à ne surtout pas traduire mot à mot j'imagine bien qu'elle me paraisse à moi, francophone, suffisamment imagée. Elle a, dans certains contexte, comme synonyme "c'est pas grave".

**Comment reformuler cette expression et comment expliquer son sens à une personne ne la connaissant pas ?**

PS : ceci n'est pas une demande de traduction mais plutôt de reformulation pour que la solution soit appliquable dans n'importe quelle autre langue.

Comment: Laisser tomber c'est simplement "ne pas continuer", "abandonner"... et quand on parle accompagner d'un geste ça aide à faire comprendre.

Comment: Moi j'opterais de la comparer avec l'expression `never mind` qui s'adapte à la plupart des contextes.

Comment: Vu toutes les propositions de traductions qui arrivent pour ta question (trois dont une de @FredP élégamment effacée suite à mon commentaire), peut-être que tu pourrais-tu reformuler ta question?

Comment: J'ai rajouté un post scriptum @Laure, aurais-tu encore le pseudo de la première personne à avoir répondu et qui a supprimé sa question ? Au delà de sa traduction il avait certains éléments de réponse intéressant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tout dépend du contexte dans lequel les interlocuteurs se trouvent

- Laisse tomber cette idée   →  Arrête de penser à cela
- Laisse tomber  →  Je ne te suis plus dans cette direction, dans cette façon de penser, dans cette action …
- Laisse tomber  →  C’est fini, il n’y a plus rien à faire
- Laisse tomber  →  Cela n’en vaut pas la peine
- Laisse tomber   →  Il y a trop de risques pour continuer

L’idée est d’arrêter ou d’abandonner une action, une pensée, un mouvement.
C’est souvent un conseil, une suggestion voire un ordre.

Answer (score 2):

L'expression «Oublie ça» est synonyme de «Laisse tomber», et est plus proche de l'expression anglophone «Never mind». Les deux expressions (en français) communiquent l'idée d'ignorer un événement qui vient de se produire, ou un énoncé qui vient d'être dit sans être pertinent.

Comment: Je n'ai pas d'exemples qui me viennent en tête à l'instant, j'en ajouterai si jamais j'y pense.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to say
"laisse tomber, ce n'est pas important"
you should say
"never mind".

If you want to say
"laisse tomber, je ne comprends rien"
you should say
"leave it there, I didn't get anything".

If you want to say
"laisse tomber, il ne comprend rien"
you should say
"stop that, he's out of reach".

If you want to say
"laisse béton", a popular verlan slang expression
you should say
"…" too rude to be written.

Comment: Cette réponse est traduction, et ne porte pas sur la langue française. french.stackexchange.com est un forum de français et le PO précise bien qu'il ne demande pas une traduction. D'ailleurs traduire en anglais ne fait pas partie du fonctionnement de french.stackexchange, merci de visiter la FAQ et en particulier [cette page](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Pour des réponses sur l'anglais il y a ELL.